# WPF Datagrid Column Width codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I would like to replace the following xaml code:

`<Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header=" " Width="*"/>` in codebehind. This xaml code fills my header to the end with my style.

This is what I want to get:

> |name | number |   this area uses     "mystyle"  end of grid ->|

This is what I currently get:

> |name | number |  unstyled area!                 end of grid ->|

As you see, I would like to fill the unstyled area with my style, done this with xaml:

`<Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header=" " Width="*"/>`

Now I need it in cb please. ;)

Comment: Your code isn't showing up. Put your code in a code sample block and check the preview before you post it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I know this is kind of late but I just had the same problem and I solve the problem using DataGridLengthUnitType.Star (well actually I use Grid but it should be the same)

```
tc.Width = New DataGridLength(2.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star); // this will make the colum to be twice as big as the others
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tc.Width = New DataGridLength(1.0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
```

Comment: ive already tried this, it doesnt work. for example if i resize the grid with the table in it , the header grows but without the style.

Comment: well, my answer only addresses the column width part. as for the style, which style did you want to apply? you can set dataGrid.Style, dataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle, dataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle or dataGridTextColumn.CellStyle